# How create value use the selected category name?

Tags: php, laravel, label

I have input label for `Title`, I need `Title` to use the selected category name.

```
<!-- parent_id -->
<?php $parentIdError = (isset($errors) and $errors->has('category_id')) ? ' is-invalid' : ''; ?>
<div class="form-group row required">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label{{ $parentIdError }}">{{ t('Category') }} <sup>*</sup></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="parent_id" id="parentId" class="form-control selecter{{ $parentIdError }}">
            <option value="0" data-type=""
                    @if (old('parent_id')=='' or old('parent_id')==0)
                        selected="selected"
                    @endif
            > {{ t('Select a category') }} </option>
            @foreach ($categories as $cat)
                <option value="{{ $cat->tid }}" data-type="{{ $cat->type }}"
                        @if (old('parent_id')==$cat->tid)
                            selected="selected"
                        @endif
                > {{ $cat->name }} </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="parent_type" id="parent_type" value="{{ old('parent_type') }}">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- category_id -->
<?php $categoryIdError = (isset($errors) and $errors->has('category_id')) ? ' is-invalid' : ''; ?>
<div id="subCatBloc" class="form-group row required">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label{{ $categoryIdError }}">{{ t('Sub-Category') }} <sup>*</sup></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="category_id" id="categoryId" class="form-control selecter{{ $categoryIdError }}">
            <option value="0"
                    @if (old('category_id')=='' or old('category_id')==0)
                        selected="selected"
                    @endif
            > {{ t('Select a sub-category') }} </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- title -->
<?php $titleError = (isset($errors) and $errors->has('title')) ? ' is-invalid' : ''; ?>
<div class="form-group row required">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="title">{{ t('Title') }} <sup>*</sup></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input id="title" name="title" placeholder="{{ t('Job title') }}" class="form-control input-md{{ $titleError }}"
               type="text" value="{{ old('title') }}">
        <small id="" class="form-text text-muted">{{ t('A great title needs at least 60 characters.') }}</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean when you select a category from dropdown it should automatically become an input value for Title input ? is this you want ?

Comment: See code snippet in answer.

Answer (score 0):

**I have removed some of your laravel code and syntax, but you get the idea, it will work same**

```js
$('#categoryId').on('change', function() {
  if ($('option:selected', this).val() != '0')
    var val = $('option:selected', this).text();
  $("#title").val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="subCatBloc" class="form-group row required">
  <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Category <sup>*</sup></label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <select name="category_id" id="categoryId" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">select category</option>
      <option value="1">Text 1</option>
      <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group row required">
  <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="title">Title <sup>*</sup></label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="title" name="title" placeholder="Job title" class="form-control input-md" type="text" value="">
    <small id="" class="form-text text-muted">A great title needs at least 60 characters.</small>
  </div>
</div>
```